# jquery :not(:first-child) wrapAll() each div

Tags: jquery, wrapall

I want to select all elements except the first in a div with that class.

Current HTML:

```
<div class="cpt-cv-content-item">
    <a>...</a>
    <h4>...</h4>
    ...
</div>
<div class="cpt-cv-content-item">
    <a>...</a>
    <h4>...</h4>
    ...
</div>
```

I tried using wrap all:

```
$(".pt-cv-content-item :not(:first-child)").wrapAll( "<div class='new'></div>" );
```

This function select correctly all element except first but moves all of them into the first div.

I want to get like this:

```
<div class="cpt-cv-content-item">
    <a>...</a>
    <div class='new'>
    <h4>...</h4>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cpt-cv-content-item">
    <a>...</a>
    <div class='new'>
    <h4>...</h4>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I cant edit the html.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the whole content, then move the first child out of the `.new` to main div.

Use **[`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)** to wrap all the children. Use **[`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)** move element to starting of an element.

```js
$(".cpt-cv-content-item").wrapInner($("<div class='new'>"));
$('div.new').each(function(){
  $(this).children().first().prependTo($(this).closest(".cpt-cv-content-item"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cpt-cv-content-item">
    <a>...</a>
    <h4>...</h4>
    ...
</div>
<div class="cpt-cv-content-item">
    <a>...</a>
    <h4>...</h4>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `wrap` instead of `wrapAll`.

```
 $(".pt-cv-content-item :not(:first-child)").wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
```

[wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

[wrapall](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.

Comment: Wrap function wraps every selected element, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I selected all elements in '.pt-cv-content-item':

```
$(".pt-cv-content-item ").wrapInner( "<div class='new'></div>" );
```

I moved out the first a href in '.pt-cv-content-item' div

```
$(".new a:first-child").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().before(this);
});
```

Thank you guys